# Can we use "Verb + ed" for future tense?

Tags: sentence-construction

Why Can't we use Verb+ed to tell future?

Example:

> If he changed this in the future, his future will be xyz.

**If suppose by mistake I changed this software code, will the employee get more salary next month?**

Is above sentence construction is correct?

Comment: they should be have+v-ed, If he has changed this in the future, his future will be xyz.
If by mistake I have changed this software code, will the employee get more salary next month?

Answer (score 2):

With *changed,* or *were to change,* you need *would.* This is a hypothetical situation.

The future would be "If I change the code, will the employee get more salary?

Answer (score 1):

"Second" conditional:

= ***If*** he chang**ed** this, his future **would be** bright.

simple past in the first clause, would + infinitive in the second clause.

Also conditional ("first" conditional)

If you **study** this example, you will **understand.** [present tense + will + infinitive]

[There is no future in these examples as they are conditionals/]